# BIRT logging in the onFetch step of a dataset

Tags: javascript, logging, dataset, birt

Im having trouble with some javascript in the onFetch step of a dataset in a BIRT report.

I've added logging in the initialise step of the report in a few different ways. The runtime im using is Tivoli Common Reporting, and they supply a logging framework. Its initialised as so

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("logfileName", "DateRangeParm.log");
setupLogging();
logInitialize();

debugLogger("Started logging in initialize step");
debugLogger("Date: " + new Date());
```

This works fine to log on the steps of the report(ie initialise, BeforeRender, AfterRender etc.) but I cant seem to log anything in the Dataset steps such as onFetch etc.

Ive also tried

```
importPackage(Packages.java.util.logging);

var fileHandler = new FileHandler("/tmp/birt.log", true);
var rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler);
```

as the BIRT instructions tell me to do in the [BIRTFAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Scripting#Q:_How_can_I_log_javascript.3F)

Once again this allowed me to log things in the main report (ie BeforeRender etc) but not in the dataset onFetch Step. Ive also tried putting the previous javascript into the onFetch and that didnt seem to work either. Its a bit of a mystery.

Im running Ubuntu 9.04. IBM java 1.5. Eclipse 3.5.0 and BIRT 2.5.1.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the onfetch method is not being called.  Is your report returning data?  And is the dataset used in the report design?

Just for kicks, try this logger

http://www.lebirtexpert.com/wordpress/2010/03/03/using-a-popup-debug-window/

Comment: your link is outdated, you should summarize the solution in your answer to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some runtime exception as i had a similar problem in beforeFactory() method, it threw exception and continued.